# when Upgrading from material-ui to @material-ui/core error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'svgIcon' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This message appeared when I was upgrading my material-ui from `material-ui` to `@material-ui/core`.
The error is at the file `node_modules/material-ui/SvgIcon/SvgIcon.js:91`

I think it has something to do with how I use my IconButtons. Since before I was using a mix of IconButton from `material-ui` and `@material-ui/icons` and now I'm importing IconButton from `@material-ui/core/IconButton`

Does anyone has any idea of how to deal with this error?